# Matlab Coder for standalone executable

Tags: matlab, executable

Using Matlab Coder is it possible to generate a completely standalone executable of my program? I'm using the Antenna Toolbox in my program and I'm not sure that after generating the executable, I can launch it without having Matlab installed, or having Matlab installed but not with that toolbox installed.

Comment: Did you try the MATLAB Compiler instead? It creates a bundle that you can run without having MATLAB installed. Most toolboxes are supported. But it doesn’t generate any C++ code, it runs the same way as when you run your code under MATLAB.

Comment: Yes, exactly. In this case it will not be stand alone but I would need to install matlab, or it will install itself all the matlab components that it needs

Comment: The Compiler generates stand-alone executables. You don’t need MATLAB. You provide your executable with the MATLAB Runtime, which is a free download. Read more here: https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that the Antenna Toolbox is not supported by the Matlab Coder: You may see the available toolboxes and functions in [Functions and Objects Supported for C/C++ Code Generation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation-categorical-list.html).

Comment: So there is no way to generate a standalone application?

Comment: Unfortunately, no